# When I export markdown in org mode, tables are exported in HTML format

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have tried ox-pandoc, but it didn't work well。I get the error

> ox-pandoc fails with `error in process sentinel: Symbol's function definition is void: run

hmm, and the issue is open for some time.

Now I want to transform this:

`| Header | Header | Right |
|--------+--------+-------|
| Cell   | Cell   | $10   |
| Cell   | Cell   | $20   |`

The result should be

`| Header | Header | Right |
|--------|--------|-------|
| Cell   | Cell   | $10   |
| Cell   | Cell   | $20   |`

Is there a way to transform the markdown file which includes HTML table content to a markdown-only file?

Comment: There is no generally accepted markdown format for tables, AFAIK. I believe that 's the reason that the org-mode markdown exporter exports tables as HTML.

Comment: Could you provide a link to ox-pandoc and to the issue that you found?

Comment: ox-pandoc is at https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc and the issue is https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc/issues/29 - AFAICT, there is now a fix for this issue: https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc/pull/33 - in my tests, I installed ox-pandoc from MELPA and running org 9.0.5 and emacs 26.50: I get no errors and the table gets translated to your desired format (at least when I select the GIthub flavor of Markdown). HTH.

Comment: @Nick yeah，thank you very much! when i upgrade org mode from 8.x to org 9.0.5, I fix it. And I just found that markdown is not support table at the begging!

Comment: @Nick  I am searching for a long time on net. But I just ignore the org version, i'm stupid